# Cleaner way to cast a C# enum

Tags: c#, enums, casting

I want to use an object (returned by framework, not in my control), `myField` which has a property `DisplayFormat` of type enum `SPNumberFormatTypes`.

I want to assign the *integer* value of DisplayFormat as a string to an `XmlAttribute`. Here is what I currently do:

```
myAttribute.Value = ((Int32)((SPNumberFormatTypes)field.DisplayFormat)).ToString();
```

One more possible way to achieve this is:

```
myAttribute.Value = ((Int32)Enum.Parse(typeof(SPNumberFormatTypes), field.DisplayFormat.ToString())).ToString();
```

I want to know if there is a simpler/cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: If `field.DisplayFormat` is already of type `SPNumberFormatTypes`, why do you need to cast it to `SPNumberFormatTypes` before casting it to Int32?  (I.e. can't you just do `((int)(field.DisplayFormat)).ToString()`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@itowlson's comment is the correct answer. Since the enum is already of type SPNumberFormatTypes, there is no need to cast it to that type. Thus my objective can be acheived in an easier way by doing this:

```
((Int32)(field.DisplayFormat)).ToString();
```

Thanks @itowlson!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, refactor what you have into an extension method, say, `ValueToString`:

```
public static string ValueToString(this SPNumberFormatTypes format) {
    int value = (int)format;
    return format.ToString();
}
```

Usage:

```
// format is SPNumberFormatType
Console.WriteLine(format.ValueToString());
```

Also, the name of your `enum` should be singular so `SPNumberFormatType`. For each member of your `enum`, say `Foo`, `SPNumberFormatType.Foo` is a format type, not a format types. This is why it should be singular. If, however, `SPNumberFormatTypes` is marked as `Flags` then you're fine, plural is standard but you should rename `DisplayFormat` to `DisplayFormats`.

Here are the [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x252001(VS.71).aspx) from MSDN.

Comment: @Aaronaught: It is most likely not a flag by it's name having the substring "NumberFormat" and being assigned to a member named "DisplayFormat." You are right though that plural is de rigueur for flags.

Answer (score 0):

How about an extension method?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx